# OpenID account got disconnected from Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, openid, meta

I've been an active Stack Overflow user for more than a year.  As of this afternoon, I cannot log in to either Stack Overflow or Meta SO.  The error message says my Open ID is not associated with an account.  I'm not sure how I got into this state.

I have only one Open ID.  I've only ever used it for SO and Meta SO.  I have tried from multiple computers and browsers.

I clicked the "Forgot your login information?" link and had SO send me the Open ID link again.  Using that link, I'm prompted for my info and successfully log into my Open ID account, but SO still claims that it's not associated with a Stack Overflow account.

Please explain how I can get this fixed?

I cannot ask this on Meta, because you cannot ask on Meta without logging in.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know the answer, but can I suggest that you create a new (temporary) account on Meta and ask this question there? It's kinda off-topic on Stack Overflow. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" was to create a new Open ID and email the Stack Overflow team to ask them to add it to my account.

Yet another third-party identity to track.

Comment: You can add your previous OpenID to your account again by using the "add openid" link on your profile page.  You can have up to 2 OpenIDs linked to your account at a time.

Comment: @Stephen Jennings: No, I cannot.  The 2nd ID is still linked to my account, but I cannot connect to StackOverflow with it.  My provider (Google) changed the hashing algorithm, and there's no way for me to generate that ID anymore.